# Reconstructing list from JSON using itertools

Tags: python, json, list

Is it possible to reconstruct this list(snippet of result):

```
[
    [
        {
            "counthigh": 3,
            "brgy_locat": "Barangay 2",
            "municipali": "Cabadbaran City"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "brgy_locat": "Barangay 2",
            "countmedium": 22,
            "municipali": "Cabadbaran City"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "brgy_locat": "Barangay 2",
            "countlow": 13,
            "municipali": "Cabadbaran City"
        }
    ]
]
```

into something like this?

```
[
    [
        {
            "counthigh": 3,
            "countmedium": 22,
            "countlow": 13,
            "brgy_locat": "Barangay 2",
            "municipali": "Cabadbaran City"
        }
    ]
]
```

The list is the output of my query in which I can't change it. I am using Django.

**EDIT**:  Let's say we have other dict of same `brgy_locat` and `municipali` with `counthigh: 5` it should add both of the values. The reconstructed list should be `counthigh:8`. Result given is just a snippet.

Comment: What should happen if you have two dicts with the same key, but different values?

Comment: Is there a problem with your current code that we could help you fix?

Answer (score 4):

Using [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> result = {}
>>> for d in chain.from_iterable(A):
...     result.update(d)
...
>>> result
{'municipali': 'Cabadbaran City', 'counthigh': 3, 'brgy_locat': 'Barangay 2', 'countmedium': 22, 'countlow': 13}
```

Comment: Thanks..I updated the question, and also I tried your method but it omits the other dicts containing different `brgy_locat`.

Comment: This should give you a starting point. From here it's just a matter of deciding what to do for each key in the inner loop.